# vue + nuxt.js - How to read POST request parameters received from an external request

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, post, nuxt.js

I have a an external form which submits a post request to my nuxt app. I am struggling currently to find out how I can access these POST request parameters in my nuxt page?

I found so far the "asyncData" method, but when I try to access the submitted parameter through the "params" object it is always "undefined". What do I wrong here?

- ["asyncData" nuxt reference](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#use-code-req-code-code-res-code-objects)

example code in my nuxt page, assuming "email" is the request parameter submitted from outside

```
export default {
 asyncData({ params }) {
    console.log('asyncData called...' + params.email);
    return {email: params.email};
},
```

external html form

```
<body>
    <form action="https://..." target="_blank" method="post">
        <input name="email" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="255"></input>
        <input name="submit" class="btn" type="submit" value="Ok"></input>
    </form>
</bod>
```

Comment: `asyncData({req})` have you tried that way?

Comment: yes but it was a little bit difficult to access the request body and its encoded parameters, see the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way, as described in ["asyncData" nuxt reference](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#use-code-req-code-code-res-code-objects) you can pass the request and response object to the "asyncData({req,res})" call.

Here an example - assuming 'email' is one of the post parameter. [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_query_string) is a module of node.js and allows you to parse the request body into an array.

Small Remark - this seems only to work for nuxt page level components but not for lower level components

```
<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ req, res }) {
     if (process.server) {
        const qs = require('querystring');
        var body = '';
        var temp = '';
        while(temp = req.read()) {
            body += temp;
        }  
        var post = qs.parse(body);
        return {data: post};
    }
  },
  data() {
     return {
          data: '',
     }
  },
  mounted() {
      console.log(this.data['email']);
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Nuxt.js cannot handle such things by itself.
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware

You should implement your own middleware for such cases.

And `asyncData` has nothing to do with handling inbound POST data.

Comment: This is not fully correct, see the asyncData() description which allows you to pass request and response object into the method call [link](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#use-code-req-code-code-res-code-objects)